# Chrome: Automatically detect language for spell checking

Tags: google-chrome, spell-checking

I use English and German interchangeably when I'm on the net with Chrome.

I really like the spell-checking functionality but find it a bit annoying that I always have to switch manually between the languages for spell checking.

Does anyone know a way how to automate that? Maybe there's a plugin?

Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

This is being tracked in issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5102. You should "star" the issue to be notified of progress.

Comment: good hint - unfortunately there is not much progress!
wow, this issue was created in dec 2008!

Comment: This is now possible - the issue has been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

There is also this one:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1834
And this design document:
http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/advancedspellchecker

The design looks a bit overkill, I hope they implement something simpler sooner.